# Linux function redirect

Tags: c, linux, linker, symbols

Hey, I'm trying to wrap a function in my program without using LD_PRELOAD.

I have two functions with the same signature:

```
void someFunc () {
    puts ("someFunc");
}

void someFunc_wrapper () {
    puts ("someFunc_wrapper");
}
```

And I want to redirect any function call to someFunc with a call to the wrapper function.
Of course I could do that with defining macros or put the wrapper function into a shared library and then call the program like this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./mylib.so my_program
```

However, I want to redirect the function calls at runtime, without modifying the program call.
As I understand, it should be possible to redirect these calls by modifying the executable's symbol table at runtime.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

`ld` has the option `--wrap=symbol` that should do what you want. The manual page has an example how it works.

Comment: Nice info. I didn't know this one.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is doable, modifying your program's symbol table might not be enough in the general case - think about the compiler inlining your function.

You could do this without dirty tricks by using an indirect function call though (always call that function via a pointer-to-function, update that pointer when you want to switch implementations).

Note that this has some runtime overhead (one more indirection). Whether that's important or not depends on the use case. And it can be turned off at compile time with macro tricks if that's just a debug feature you're implementing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void) {
    printf("Hello from foo\n");
}

void bar(void) {
    printf("Hello from bar\n");
}

#ifdef INTERCEPT

typedef void(*myfunptr)(void);

myfunptr thingy = foo;

void turnonbar(void)
{
    thingy = bar;
}

#else
#define turnonbar()
#define thingy foo
#endif

int main(void) {
    thingy();
    turnonbar();
    thingy();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
Yes, I could use a function pointer, which would be the best way normally.
But I would really like to know how to manipulate the symbol table to achieve this, since there are a lot of cases where wrapping function calls would be incredibly useful, without needing access to the source code and to recompile the application. :)